# Trying to find a book in which a girl can change the colors of everything but herself

Tags: story-identification, books

It is a book in which a girl has the power to change the color of others and other things, except herself. She goes on a journey with this guy to save her family (?) and I remember they get lost in a forest. There’s this huge contest to determine her skill in this town, and she gets a 0.

I do remember the cover art; which shows the girl, who has white hair and white skin, and the boy, who has white hair but a tan skin tone. The girl has a red traditional dress on, and the boy has a blue grey hoodie. The background color of the cover is red.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Please note however that story-ID questions should only ask about one story per question, so I suggest that you post two separate questions here, one for each book. It'd also be beneficial to look through the check lists in [this thread](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question), and use them as a guide to add as much relevant information to each question as you're able to. The more info you provide, the better the chances that someone can ID these books for you.

Comment: Hi and welcome, please take the [tour] and visit the [help] when able. @LogicDictates is correct, so I have gone ahead and closed your question until you can [edit] your post to focus on just one, and post the second one as a separate [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) (don't worry you can ask as many as you want.) When you've added enough detail, the community will reopen you posts ready to be answered.

Comment: If you're certain these were two books in the same series, it's a valid question, and you need to indicate that.

Comment: Is this actually fanfiction, based off on an existing property? And is this a novel with words, a comic book, or a mix of the two?

Comment: If you have found the answer, post it. You will be able to accept in 41 hours, 2 days after you asked the question. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28110143-furthermore for reference.

Comment: Hi Hikanaaa :-) Since you have found the book would you like to post an answer saying what the book is?

Answer (score 9):

The book is called *[Furthermore](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/28110143-furthermore)* by Tahereh Mafi! From what I remember it’s an incredible book that you all should read! It’s very whimsical and fun.

[image: Front cover of Furthermore]

> Alice Alexis Queensmeadow 12 rates three things most important: Mother, who wouldn’t miss her; magic and color, which seem to elude her; and Father, who always loved her. Father disappeared from Ferenwood with only a ruler, almost three years ago. But she will have to travel through the mythical, dangerous land of Furthermore, where down can be up, paper is alive, and left can be both right and very, very wrong. Her only companion is Oliver whose own magic is based in lies and deceit. Alice must first find herself—and hold fast to the magic of love in the face of loss.

Comment: ^_^ Congrats on posting the answer. Please stick around to accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons (it may tell you you need to wait another day). I edited the Goodreads summary into a quote in the answer because it makes it more searchable.